# How to use Symfony 2.7 ChoiceType with php 5.4?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to update Symfony to the 2.7 API for choiceList. The [symfony manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) has the example:

```
$builder->add('isAttending', ChoiceType::class, array(
```

Which for php 5.4 I translated to

```
$builder->add('graduatedSince', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType', array(
```

However, I get a "Could not load type" error. What is the syntax?

Comment: Look at the 2.7 version of the documents: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html (as opposed to the current 3.x version).  Lots of form changes between 2.7 and 2.8/3.x.

Comment: Just leave it as 'choice' then, but the 'choices_as_values' thing is new. That is what I reverted to and the form renders.

Comment: Yep.  They swapped array keys and values between 2.7 and 2.8.  Again, just be sure you are reading the 2.7 docs.  Or save yourself some trouble and just upgrade your php version so you can use 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for Symfony 2.7 is

```
$builder->add('isAttending', 'choice', array(
    'choices'  => array(
        'Maybe' => null,
        'Yes' => true,
        'No' => false,
    ),
    // *this line is important*
    'choices_as_values' => true,
));
```

Here is the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html)